# GO,VS code : no completion for external packages (intellisense)

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

I installed VS code and go extension 
It completes words from internal packages of the language like `fmt` but not from external packages 
for example `SDL` 
I searched but nothing 
I use **GO modules**
last version of VS code and go
OS : Linux (if this will help i don't know)

Answer (score 0):

Search for a plugin which does that. I remember I had that problem with css and needed a plugin for that.

I don't remember the plugin I used but I'll do some search and if I find it I'll let you know. But I'm 100% sure that installing a plugin for that will resolve the issue.

Comment: i installed one but i think will have to try others

Comment: I did some search and apparently the one I used is no longer available :/ I tried to find a github repository with it so that you could fork but couldn't find anything